# How to rewrite the core.logic snippet?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I'm trying to rewrite the below piece of `core.logic` code.

```
(run* [x y]
    (fd/in x (fd/domain 1 2))
    (fd/in y (fd/domain 1 2)))
```

**o/p,**

> ([1 1] [2 1] [1 2] [2 2])

I tried the below versions but none of them works,

```
(run* [x y]
    (fresh [dom (fd/domain 1 2)])
        (fd/in x dom)
        (fd/in y dom)))
```

**;; Error Unsupported binding form: (fd/domain 1 2)**

```
(run* [x y]
 (fresh [dom]
    (== dom  (fd/domain 1 2))
    (fd/in x dom)
    (fd/in y dom)))
```

**O/P:**

> ([1 1])

```
(run* [x y]
  (let [dom (fd/domain 1 2)]
  (fd/in x dom)
  (fd/in y dom)))
```

**O/P:**

> ([_0 1] [_0 2])

What's the rationale for the 3 versions that I tried? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fd/domain` returns a concrete value that can be used with other goals/relations in the `fd` namespace — you can define it once and use it inside `run*` more than once:

```
(let [dom (fd/domain 1 2)]
  (run* [x y]
    (fd/in x dom)
    (fd/in y dom)))
=> ([1 1] [2 1] [1 2] [2 2])
```

> What's the rationale for the 3 versions that I tried?

The first refactoring doesn't work because `fresh` is being used like `let`, but it doesn't work like that; `fresh` simply allows you to give names to some fresh logic variables.

The second refactoring doesn't work because the domain value is being bound to a logic variable, and `fd/in` wants a concrete domain value as its second argument — not a (fresh) logic variable.

The third refactoring doesn't work (I assume) because `let` bindings aren't going to work like that *inside* the `run*` macro, which only wants a sequence of *goals* in its body.